# Complexity of comparing extended integer power towers

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, time-complexity, polynomial-time, open-problem

Inspired by [this stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101138/complexity-class-of-comparison-of-power-towers), is it an open problem to compare two power towers of positive integers if we additionally allow numbers lower in the tower to themselves be represented by power towers? Example:

$$(2^3)^{(4^{5^3})^5}$$

It seems to me like the accepted answer on that page requires a bound on the sizes of the numbers lower in the tower in order to work.